# Is it safe to update an old site after backing it up and activating a child theme?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme, updates, backup

I am pretty new to WP and WooCommerce and have been asked to do some basic SEO work on a site which has not been updated for quite a while.

I created and activated a child theme and backed it up using Updraft.
This is the message I get:

"Your theme (Ronneby Child) contains outdated copies of some WooCommerce template files. These files may need updating to ensure they are compatible with the current version of WooCommerce. You can see which files are affected from the system status page. If in doubt, check with the author of the theme"

On System Status Page I get a long list of Overrides (under the Templates tab) that are out of date.

How can I make sure it is okej to update them all? Currently using WooCommerce 3.0.4 and WP 4.7.10

Any information on how to proceed to get everything up to date would be appreciated, the less techie answers the better, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Backup all, and download that backup or save it on cloud. Proceed with updating, first update theme version, parent theme, plugins, and then wordpress core version, after that check if anything else left to update. After everything check all function. If some problems, repeat everything and check functions after each step.